# Using ajax to dynamically populate model attribute

Tags: java, ajax, dojo, spring-roo

I am currently working on a Spring Roo project that uses the standard Dojo front-end. I would like one of my select boxes to be dynamically loaded based on the option selected from the previous select. The .jspx file looks like this:

```
<form:create id="fc_za_co_itdynamics_survey_domain_Hierarchy" modelAttribute="hierarchy" path="/hierarchys" render="${empty dependencies}" z="uMMWuqMHFrh8u9++PH5WZfwEDGg=">
    <field:input field="name" id="c_za_co_itdynamics_survey_domain_Hierarchy_name" min="2" required="true" z="0obmzH2lsnbEXbepG3O0z8Sl0SE="/>
    <field:select field="type" id="c_za_co_itdynamics_survey_domain_Hierarchy_type" items="${hierarchytypeenums}" path="hierarchytypeenums" required="true" z="DstTv0Lvaswu9kaBdPwzpxdy9ZQ="/>
    <field:select field="parentHierarchy" id="c_za_co_itdynamics_survey_domain_Hierarchy_parentHierarchy" itemValue="id" items="${hierarchys}" path="/hierarchys" z="7w1IXuZxyYUBZ/VIhDvss5HnIUw="/>
</form:create>
```

So basically I would like the ${hierarchies} collection for the ***parentHierarchy*** field to be dynamically populated whenever the ***type*** field is changed.

The controller method that should be called is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getHierarchiesForType", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Hierarchy> getHierarchiesForType(@RequestParam("type") String typeStr){
    ......
    .....
    return hierarchyList;
}
```

I am thinking of using an Ajax call to call the controller method whenever the ***type*** is changed. My code will be as follows

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    var hierarchyType = dijit.byId("_type_id");
    dojo.connect(hierarchyType,"onChange",function(){
        var url = "${ajax_url}?type=" + hierarchyType;
        dojo.xhrGet({
            url : url,
            handleAs : "??",
            preventCache: true,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "??"
            },
            load : function(data){
                ......
            },
            error : function(error) {
                console.log("error", error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

How can I map the results of such a call to the ${hierarchies} attribute? If so, is this the best way of doing it? Is it even possible for a model attribute to be dynamically changed/generated?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
handleAs: "json",
```

and

```
"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Also, include Jackson library in your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```